# MySqlDataReader returns different type for same column if UNION ALL is used

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a loop through a DataReader generated from a MySqlCommand where it's query selects from some fields including 2 `TINYINT(1)` fields that are mapped to `bool`s on C# and this is what I'm expecting it to be.

The problem arose while I've changed the query to do an `UNION ALL` with the same table.
After I've changed the query, I've began to get an invalid convertion error. The `TINYINT(1)` columns now return `SByte`s instead of `Boolean`.

Is this a MySql Server problem? A MySql Net/Connector problem? Is this an expected behaviour?

**Example query:**

```
string sql = @"SELECT tinyint1column FROM mytable WHERE id = 1";

command.CommandText = sql;

using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        bool flag = (bool)reader["tinyint1column"]; // OK - No error
    }
}

sql = @"SELECT tinyint1column FROM mytable WHERE id = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT tinyint1column FROM mytable WHERE id = 2";

command.CommandText = sql;

using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        bool flag = (bool)reader["tinyint1column"]; // Invalid cast error???
    }
}
```

**Before someone asks:**

- I have a MySql Server 5.1 installed on a shared host so I CAN'T upgrade the server.
- I'm using MySql.Data version 6.5.4 because it's the only one I could compile to run on this shared host with medium/partial thrust.
- I'm actually "casting" the reader to a `List<DbDataRecord>` with the `.Cast<>()` extension method to get a "disconected reader", but it does not change the underlying data in any way.

Comment: Edit your question and include the query you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a MySql issue or a connector issue, but it's a problem.

After getting some inspiration from @Steve's answer I've came with a solution:

```
public static class DbDataRecordExtensions
{
    public static bool GetBoolean(this DbDataRecord rec, string fieldName)
    {
        var index = rec.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
        var value = rec.GetValue(index);

        if (value is bool || value is Boolean)
        {
            return (bool)value;
        }
        else if (value is SByte || value is sbyte)
        {
            return (sbyte)value != 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return rec.GetInt64(index) != 0;
        }
    }
}
```

There is not way I can do a universal cast because it changes the type when both queries on the union return rows, so I've wrote some conditions to overcome this.

Please note that for `MySqlDataReader` you will have to change the extension method signature and method name:

```
GetBooleanEx(this MySqlDataReader rec, string fieldName)
```

Comment: Well we have reached the same conclusion.. now considering that a TINYINT(1) is never greater than 127 or less than -128 and everything that is not zero is true....

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the problem(?) also with NET Connector 6.3.

However there is an easy way out calling `reader.GetBoolean()`.
This override of the base IDbDataReader in the MySql Connector internally calls Convert.ToBoolean() on the reader field

```
public bool GetBoolean(string name)
{
    return this.GetBoolean(this.GetOrdinal(name));
}

public override bool GetBoolean(int i)
{
    return Convert.ToBoolean(this.GetValue(i));
}
```

so you could easily adapt your code to this situation (and it works also for the single table version of your query)

```
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        bool flag = reader.GetBoolean("tinyint1column"); 
        ....
    }
}
```

**EDIT**   Given your comments below, I think that you could resolve the problem for the missing GetBoolean(fieldName) with an extension method for the DbDataRecord class.
I have tested this with LinqPad and it seems to work correctly (A part from what to return if the field is null)

```
public bool GetBoolean(DbDataRecord rec, string fieldName)
{
    int pos = rec.GetOrdinal(fieldName);
    if(rec.IsDBNull(pos))
        return false; // ??

    object result = rec.GetValue(pos);   
    return Convert.ToBoolean(result);
}
```

Comment: Sadly I'm casting the reader to a `List<DbDataRecord>` with `var list = reader.Cast<DbDataRecord>().ToList()` so I can pass around and dispose the reader.

Comment: how come you are not showing all relevant code then.. you are confusing the issue currently..

Comment: I am thinking to an extension method for DbDataRecord then, but cannot test here now. Something on the line of `bool result = !(dbrecord.GetValue(1) == (object)0);` where the field at index 1 is your tinyint1column

Comment: Nope. All relevant code is there. You can reproduce the issue with the code I gave so the problem is not with my approuch. What I've actually want to mean with the above statement is that your solution should work if I use the reader directly, but I'm casting it to a list to use it disconnected from the database. The `DbDataRecord` does not have the `GetBoolean(string fieldname)` overload. It has only the `GetBoolean(int index)` version.

Comment: Also, if you note, I've added this info to the question before you've posted your answer.

Comment: It didn't work. Threw the same exception when the 2 queries from the union return results.

Comment: Thank you for you effort, but it didn't work either. I've found a solution based on yours.

Comment: Now I am really interested, could you give an explain?